# Vapor client close stream

Tags: client, vapor

App upload through the interface to the server, the server and then upload the picture to the storage space.I know my method is not the best If there are good ways to thank share

code look like this:

with main.swift

```
let config = try Config()
try config.addProvider(PostgreSQLProvider.Provider.self)

let drop = try Droplet(config)

let fleCrl = FileController();
fleCrl.addRoutest(drop: drop);
drop.resource("files", fleCrl);
```

with FileController.swift

```
final class FileController: ResourceRepresentable{

var drop:Droplet?;

public func addRoutest(drop: Droplet) -> Void {
    self.drop = drop;
    let d = drop.grouped("file");
    d.post("updateFile", handler: updateFile)
}

func updateFile(req:Request) throws -> ResponseRepresentable {

    let picName =  req.data["name"]?.string ?? String();
    let bytes:[UInt8] = (req.data["data"]?.bytes)!;
    let request = Request(method:.post,uri:"http://up.qiniu.com");

    let t = "image/\(picName)";
    let token = req.data["token"]?.bytes;

    request.formData = [
        "token":Field(name:"token",filename:nil,part:Part(headers:[:], body: token!)),
        "file":Field(name:"file",filename:t,part:Part(headers:["Content-Type": "vnd.apple.mpegURL"],body:bytes)),
        "key":Field(name:"key",filename:t,part:Part(headers:[:],body:t.bytes))
    ]

    let resp = try self.drop?.client.respond(to: request);

    return resp?.data["info"]?.string;
   }

}
```

with client

```
    let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: URL.init(string: "video.m3u8")!);

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

        multipartFormData.append(data!, withName: "data", fileName: "video", mimeType:"application/x-mpegURL")

        multipartFormData.append("videoName".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "name")

    }, to: "http://0.0.0.0:8083/file/updateFile") { (encodingResult) in

        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
```

The server console is reported as follows

```
[Stream Error: The stream is closed] [Identifier: Transport.StreamError.closed]
```